# A faster way to find the term $x^0$ in the expansion of $(1-\frac{x}{3})^{5}(1+\frac{2}{x})^{3}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Now I am actually looking for a method in the general case when you have a product of two binomials. The method I use is equating coefficients; I have provided my example solution to this question as an answer. Now this is a pretty good method I reckon but I wonder if someone out there has a faster, more efficient solution to these types of questions that they would like to share (please?). The thing that annoys me is plugging huge sums of numbers into the calculator that takes more time than the answer itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will not claim  this is faster ....

as $${(1+\frac{2}{x})}^3=\frac{{(x+2)}^3}{x^3}$$

we have to find the coefficient of $x^3$ in $$f(x)={(x+2)}^3{(1-x/3)}^5=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4..+a_8x^8$$

Notice that  $$f'''(x)=6a_3+24a_4x+..$$
$$f'''(0)=6a_3$$ From here can you finish it?

Comment: Should the 2 be 2/x and the "find the coefficient of x^3" be x^0? Or are you making up your own example?

Comment: @user71207 its the same i manipulated it

Comment: I do not understand how differentiating will work in this case. Could you explain or link me to more resources for clarification? How do you know the coefficient is 6?

Comment: @user71207 differentiate thrice the RHS and then put $x=0$ higher coefficents dssappear.

Comment: Are you sure its the same? Everything is the same except for the 2 in the first binomial you wrote

Comment: hmmm ok. Whats the name of this technique? I still don't understand where the $f'''(0) = 6$ came from

Comment: @user71207 t did you triple differentiate what do you get?

Comment: Yes I tried it - and got what you mean. Thanks. Two more questions:



1) Why are we looking for x^3 when we should be looking for the constant term



2) How does $6a_3$ relate to the answer 37/27

Comment: @user71207 triple differentiate the LHS this may be a bit lengthy and put x=0 you should get $37/27$

Comment: @user71207 you are looking for constant term ,i multiplied the whole expression by $x^3$ to get $f(x)$ hence we look for coefficient of $x^3$

Comment: Oh so you use the coefficient from differentiating the RHS to plug into the differentiated LHS. That could be lengthy because of repeated product rule. It way be more convenient for some questions - thanks I've never seen this way before. Very interesting to see calculus pop up here. I don't have an extremely strong understand of calculus in this case so I would really appreciate if you explain **why** it works here

Comment: @user71207 its difficult to explain why it works its jaut atrick that works for some problems.Nevertheess your method is better in this case

Answer (score 1):

Using the binomial theorem,
\begin{align*}
\left( 1 - \frac{x}{3} \right)^5 &= \sum_{i=0}^{5} \binom{5}{i} 1^{5-i} \left(\frac{-x}{3} \right)^i  \\
    &= \sum_{i=0}^5 \binom{5}{i} (-3)^{-i} x^i  \text{ and }  \\
\left( 1 + \frac{2}{x} \right)^3 &= \sum_{j=0}^{3} \binom{3}{j}1^{3-j} \left(\frac{2}{x} \right)^j  \\
    &= \sum_{j=0}^{3} \binom{3}{j} 2^j x^{-j}
\end{align*}
So \begin{align*}
\left( 1 - \frac{x}{3} \right)^5 \left( 1 + \frac{2}{x} \right)^3
    &= \left( \sum_{i=0}^5 \binom{5}{i} (-3)^{-i} x^i \right) \left( \sum_{j=0}^{3} \binom{3}{j} 2^j x^{-j} \right)  \\
    &= \sum_{i=0}^5 \sum_{j=0}^{3} \binom{5}{i} \binom{3}{j} (-3)^{-i} 2^j x^{i-j}
\end{align*}
The only contributions to $x^0$ have $i - j = 0$, so $i = j$.  The range of $i$ is $[0,5]$ and the range of $j$ is $[0,3]$.  The intersection of these two intervals is $[0,3]$, so we have four terms contributing to the coefficient of $x^0$:
$$  \sum_{j=0}^{3} \binom{5}{j} \binom{3}{j} (-3)^{-j} 2^j  $$
(It seems that we have done a lot of work to get here.  With practice, you can jump straight to this expression.)
Call the four terms $a_j = \binom{5}{j} \binom{3}{j} (-3)^{-j} 2^j$ for $j \in [0,3]$.  Notice
$$ a_0 = \binom{5}{0} \binom{3}{0} (-3)^{-0} 2^0 = 1  \text{.}  $$
Then
\begin{align*}
a_1 &= a_0 \cdot \frac{5}{1} \cdot \frac{3}{1} \cdot \frac{-1}{3} \cdot 2 = -10  \text{,}  \\
a_2 &= a_1 \cdot \frac{4}{2} \cdot \frac{2}{2} \cdot \frac{-1}{3} \cdot 2 = \frac{40}{3}  \text{, and}  \\
a_3 &= a_2 \cdot \frac{3}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{-1}{3} \cdot 2 = \frac{-80}{27}  
\end{align*}
This says we can compute the next term from the previous one.  The second and third factors are the old mental arithmetic method for calculating rows of Pascal's triangle by multiplying by successive fractions having decreasing numerators and increasing denominators.

Then the coefficient of $x^0$ is
$$  1 - 10 + \frac{40}{3} - \frac{80}{27} = \frac{37}{27}  \text{.}  $$

Answer (score 0):

It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ of a series.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^0]}&\color{blue}{\left(1+\frac{2}{x}\right)^3\left(1-\frac{x}{3}\right)^5}\\
> &=[x^0]\sum_{j=0}^3\binom{3}{j}2^jx^{-j}\left(1-\frac{x}{3}\right)^5\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^3\binom{3}{j}2^j[x^j]\left(1-\frac{x}{3}\right)^5\tag{2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{j=0}^3\binom{3}{j}\binom{5}{j}2^j\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^j}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
> and the result can be manually calculated by summing up $4$ terms.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the binomial theorem to the left-hand binomial.
- In (2) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule $[x^p]x^qA(x)=[x^{p-q}]A(x)$.
- In (3) we select the coefficient of $x^j$.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

My way:

1. Find the general term for both binomials separately
2. To find the independent term, consider the possible expansions by inspection then plug in the appropriate values into the general terms
3. Use calculator to sum up values (very lengthy process if there are lots of cases)